# Generating Code Coverage in scrutinizer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, code-coverage, scrutinizer

I created a little package and I want to get some qualifications for it.
So one of them is `Scrutinizer` Coverage and Code Quality.
As in the tutorial I created a file and renamed it to `scrutinizer.yml` and put the following into it:

```
build:
tests:
    override:
        -
            command: 'vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-clover=some-file'
            coverage:
                file: 'some-file'
                format: 'clover'
```

But after syncing in my `Scrutinizer` profile I get this "coverage NaN%"

So what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I found it.
it related to setting of PHPUnit. i create a file and renamed it to phpunit.xml and put following configuration code to it.

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnFailure="false"
     syntaxCheck="false"
>
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Package Test Suite">
        <directory suffix=".php">./tests/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

and after a ran phpunit for create local coverage.xml file; it given to me following error:

```
Error:         No code coverage driver is available
```

and i after a little search it found i have to insert following code into phpunit.xml

```
<filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

so final phpunit.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Package Test Suite">
            <directory suffix=".php">./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```